# stringByAppendingPathCompnent is unavailable

Tags: swift, filepath

Hmm the usual Swift upgrades rewrites required. My venerable path command no longer works saying "stringByAppendingPathCompnent is unavailable"

```
return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

If I use URLByAppendingComponent as instructed

```
return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

I am told that value of type String has no member URLByAppointmentPathComponent

How should I go about resolving this?

Comment: I went through that question before I posted mine and couldn't work out how it answered my issue. This could easily be my lack of experience but am finding the Swift 2.0 change instructions convoluted. Appreciated,

Comment: Cast the String to NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that you can try this:

```
return try!  NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).path!
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)